# MVC Disabled DropDownlistValue not posting selected key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, dropdown

I'm having a problem to retreive the dropdownlist selectedted key.

Here is my edit event, when I find the register by ID, and send it to View.
At this moment everything is fine.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = _mapper.Mapear(_dispositivoService.ConsultarPorId(id));
    model.ListaProfissionaisAtivos = new SelectList(_profissionalService.ListarAtivos(), "ProfissionalID", "Nome", model.ProfissionalID);    
    return View(model);
}
```

Here is my DropDownList. Everything OK. All items are there, and the item ID which was saved on database is selected.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProfissionalID", Model.ListaProfissionaisAtivos, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

But after post form data, every prperty are fiilled, excet the one which is the Key of DropDownList: ProfissionalID

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ProfissionalDispositivoViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        model.ListaProfissionaisAtivos = new SelectList(_profissionalService.ListarAtivos(), "ProfissionalID", "Nome", model.ProfissionalID);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var dominio = _mapper.Mapear(model);
            _dispositivoService.Atualizar(dominio);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Mensagem = ex.Message;
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

It seems that MVC doesn't post value of disabled controls. My dropdownlist is disabled. But I need to keep this property value to save chages without errors. How can I do this and deny user to edit this field?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Include a hidden input for the property (and delete the dropdownlist - there is not point rendering unnecessary html - just render the display name associated with the selected item)

Comment: Also realize this is how html works and not specific to asp.net mvc.  Disabled inputs never post their values back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Yes disabled control values wont be posted. So what you can do is enable the controls on button click and then it will work. Or else while binding the dropdownlist bind the value to some hidden field and then make the dropdownlist disabled. Now on the form post you can get the value from hidden field.